# How to get indexed ListView on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView. I want to add a dummy widget to 0 index without remove actual value. Is there any way to get index?

```
 final result = model.where((a) => a.subCategoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query));
```

**ListView**

```
return ListView(
  children: result
      .map<InkWell>((a) => InkWell(
            //code
      )).toList(););
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter widgets has a widget called ScrollablePositionedList. Maybe it can help you. 
Example of its use [here](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/blob/master/example/scrollable_positioned_list/lib/scrollable_positioned_list_example.dart)

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: result.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
                  return ind == 0
                      ? Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          child: Text('Dummy Widget'))
                      : ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                          title: Text(result[ind - 1]),
                          onTap: () {
                            //Original item with index -1 !
                          });
                })
```

Comment: you can't use `[]` with `Iterable<>`

Comment: Oops ! Add this ##.  result.map........toList();  ## to a list variable in a separate method or in init state !